# create folder in android not working?

Tags: android, directory

I want to create a folder in adcart but don't work I tested this code

```
  String Dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/android/android0/data";
            Boolean H=new File(Dir).mkdirs();
```

**This code in android 4.4 and 6 not working on emulator too**

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Example");
    boolean success = true;
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        success = folder.mkdirs();
    }
    if (success) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

please help i need create folder in all version android

Comment: Have you add WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: @mohammad fathi jorabi your targetSdk ?